# I am trying to create an http2 multiclient server using python hyper library. It completes only the first request

Tags: python, select, socketserver, python-sockets, hyper

I am able to serve http2 using this tutorial. https://python-hyper.org/projects/h2/en/stable/basic-usage.html. This version works fine. But this server is able to serve only one client in a time, becouse of the blocking sockets.
Then I looked for multiclient server implementations, based on `select()` systemcall. This tutorial showed me how to do it. https://realpython.com/python-sockets/. I merged the two tutorials, to create an http2 multiclient-serving server.
This is what I ended up with:

*server.py*

```
import json
import socket

import h2.connection
import h2.events

import types
from thread import start_new_thread
try:
    import selectors
except ImportError:
    import selectors2 as selectors

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
h2conn = h2.connection.H2Connection(client_side=False)

def send_response(hyperConn, event):
    print ('sending respond')
    stream_id = event.stream_id
    response_data = json.dumps(dict(event.headers))+'KUKA MAKI'.encode('utf-8')

    hyperConn.send_headers(
        stream_id=stream_id,
        headers=[
            (':status', '200'),
            ('server', 'basic-h2-server/1.0'),
            ('content-length', str(len(response_data))),
            ('content-type', 'application/json'),
        ],
    )
    hyperConn.send_data(
        stream_id=stream_id,
        data=response_data,
        end_stream=True
    )

def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    print("accepted connection from", addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)

    data = lambda: None    # Dummy namespace
    data.addr = addr
    data.inb = b''
    data.outb = b''
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)
    h2InitConn = h2.connection.H2Connection(client_side=False)
    h2InitConn.initiate_connection()
    conn.sendall(h2InitConn.data_to_send())


def service_connection(key, mask):

    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data

    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(65535)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            # data.outb += recv_data
            print ('raw data: ', recv_data)
            events = h2conn.receive_data(recv_data)
            print 'events received:' , events
            for event in events:
                if isinstance(event, h2.events.RequestReceived):
                    print ('request recieved')
                    send_response(h2conn, event)

        else:
            print("closing connection to", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        data_to_send = h2conn.data_to_send()
        if data_to_send:
            print("replying with stuff to", data.addr)
            sock.sendall(data_to_send)

lsock = socket.socket()
lsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host, port = '0.0.0.0' , 8080
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen(5)
print("listening on", (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)


sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)
try:
    while True:
        events = sel.select(timeout=None)
        for key, mask in events:
            if key.data is None:
                accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
            else:
                service_connection(key, mask)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
finally:
    sel.close()
```

If I run python *server.py*, and in another terminal I run the hyper CLI tool, to send http2 request ( `hyper --h2 GET http://localhost:8080/` ). The first request is succesful, I can see the events generated, and the hyper tool shows the resonds and quits nicely. After that sending the same hyper command again there are no events generated by the request, and the CLI tool hangs as well. Could you help me figuring out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out.

I had to save the state of the http2 connection in the accept_wrapper function into a dictionary, where the key is the client socket address. In the service_connection function I parsed the data with the appropriate saved http2 connection object, and then It produced events.

at the begining of the file:

```
h2conns = {}
```

end of the  the accept_wrapper function accept_wrapper:

```
h2conns[conn.getpeername()[1]] = h2InitConn
```

in the servie_connection function:

```
h2conn = h2conns[sock.getpeername()[1]]
```